# Git Merge with a sub-file

Tags: git

I have two branches,

**branch 1**:

```
root
  |_ project_1
  |_ file1.txt
  |_ file2.txt
```

**branch 2**:

```
project_2
```

where **`branch1` and `branch2` has different origins** and the `project_1` and `project_2` has exactly same structures and most files are shared. And I want to merge `branch2` into `branch1`(more explicitly, merge `project_2` into `project_1`, the dir) and keep the structure of `branch2`.

So the end state would be like:

```
root
  |_ project_2
  |_ file1.txt
  |_ file2.txt
```

How to resolve it?

I think there is a way is to:

1. `git pull branch1`
2. and delete `project_1`
3. and move `project_2` into `root` folder.

But I wonder if it is safe to do so, as I would like to keep some files of `project_1` if they are not existed in `project_2`.

Comment: what is the final state you want to obtain? Do you just want to crush all files from project_1 with the files from project_2? Please make sure your question is clear enough to answer, for now it is impossible to know what you want to obtain.

Comment: project_1 and project_2 mostly are the same, merging them two wont crush any files

Comment: It still isn't clear, can you **explicitly** say what you want the end goal to be? Describe it, give an example. For instance, where should `project_1` end up? What about `file1.txt`?

Comment: Also, does the two branches have the same origin? Same base commit at some point? Because if so, then it looks like either branch 1 *added* those 3 things, or branch 2 *deleted* those 3 tings and replaced it with `project_2`. Can you elaborate on how you came about having those two branches like this?

Comment: sry for confusing, I will fix it

Comment: If you work in a fresh sandbox, you can test your idea and see if you get the results you want. If it worked, great, if not, throw away that sandbox and start again, nothing lost!